# Google Charts - interpolateNulls option not working for AnnotationChart

Tags: google-visualization

I'm a beginner with Google Visualizations.  I'm having trouble with getting the "interpolateNulls: true" option working correctly with an AnnotationChart.  If I use the same datasets with a basic LineChart, it works as expected.  Here is my code and resulting charts:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
  google.load('visualization', '1.1', {'packages':['Annotationchart']});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$json1?>);
    var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$json2?>);

    var joinedData = google.visualization.data.join(data1, data2, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1], [1]);

    var chart1 = new google.visualization.AnnotationChart(document.getElementById('chart1'));

    var options = {
      displayAnnotations: false,
  thickness: 2,
  colors: ['red', 'blue'],
  interpolateNulls: true,
      curveType: 'function',
    };

    chart1.draw(joinedData, options);
  }
```

produces:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kHv6.jpg

Whereas:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
  google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$json1?>);
    var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$json2?>);

    var joinedData = google.visualization.data.join(data1, data2, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1], [1]);

    var chart1 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart1'));

    var options = {
      displayAnnotations: false,
  thickness: 2,
  colors: ['red', 'blue'],
  interpolateNulls: true,
      curveType: 'function',
    };

    chart1.draw(joinedData, options);
  }
```

produces:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YOKv.jpg

What am I missing?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AnnotationChart has no option `interpolateNulls`. See google docs [Annotation Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotationchart).

Comment: Thanks.  I knew there was something simple I was missing.  I'm looking into moving this project over to Dygraphs now.

Comment: You can get similar functionality to an AnnotationChart by using a [ChartRangeFilter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#chartrangefilter) and a LineChart in a [Dashboard](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#dashboardobject).

Comment: Thanks I'll check that out.  In the meantime, I was able to get dygraphs working.  Took a while to properly format the data but it's working and it looks great!